# Can fetishes or talens step sideways by themselves?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse, werewolf-20th-anniversary

In my Werewolf game, the players have to assassinate someone. A rank 1 theurge wants to shoot the target with a sniper rifle.

But they want to make the bullet a talen that enters the Umbra when it’s fired, then exits just before it hits its target. Their theory is the bullet will be invisible and can pass though walls.

As this sounds like a very Glass Walker or Weaver tech thing to do, is there anything in the core rules or supplements that would allow or disallow this (like a variant of the rank 4 gift “[Grasp From Beyond](http://www.wyrmfoe.com/176/grasp-the-beyond/)”)?

My instinct is to rule “no”, but I’d prefer to have concrete grounds for doing so, as I hate being an arbitrary judge.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another Werewolf player suggested the rank 2 theurge gift "[Spirit Knife](http://www.wyrmfoe.com/1110/spirit-knife/)" from the *Book of Auspices* could do this as it allows weapons to strike at opponents through the Gauntlet. However, the gift is limited to "hand-crafted" weapons, so the garou would have to make their own rifle and bullets.

> **Spirit Knife**
>
> *Rank 2 Theurge Gift*
>
> Using this Gift, a Theurge can imbue a knife — or any other weapon she
> hand-crafted herself — with the power to strike across the Gauntlet,
> affecting enemies on the other side. This Gift conveys no ability to
> see across the Gauntlet beyond what the Garou normally possesses,
> however. A Wasp-spirit teaches this Gift.
>
> System: The Garou spends one Gnosis point, and any single weapon she
> crafted entirely herself is able to strike
> creatures on either side of the Gauntlet in any area
> where the Gauntlet is equal to or lower than her Gnosis. This effect
> lasts for the duration of the scene.

Comment: Note that depending on "entirely by himself" may not be as hard. Sport shooters make their own bullets quite regularly, and lead balls and black powder for older, blackpowder guns is entirely doable.

Comment: In this case, I consider the "weapon" to be the sniper rifle and its ammunition. So while it's just about possible for this particular garou to make the high-quality ammunition a sniper rifle would require (which means making all the parts of a bullet from scratch – nothing bought from a shop or made by someone else), they'd still have to make the actual sniper rifle by hand themselves.

Comment: "making all the parts of a bullet from scratch" is tricky. Do they need to smelt steel for knife to do it? And so on. You have to stop *somewhere* for this to be ever usable.

Comment: True. You could go back to "The theurge has to mine the iron ore themselves." But if a Bone Gnawer theurge hand-made a shank or slingshot, I'd likely allow them to use it with this gift, as I think it's the spiritual bond the theurge forms with the weapon from investing skill, time and energy in making it that matters. As for other weapons, we have to keep in mind that some theurges are excellent blacksmiths, as klaives exist and Get have fetishised axes and warhammers. So a Glass Walker engineer/gunsmith theurge might be able pull off this plan. But my player's theurge can't.